# Какая подробная характеристика у данного предложения? И какой частью речи является "и" ( I, II)?

Tags: синтаксис

В родительском доме всё было по-прежнему, и если Володе и казалось домашнее пространство как будто сузившемся, то это только оттого что за годы отсутствия он очень повзрослел и вырос.

Опишите это предложение подробно и с пояснениями. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

В родительском доме всё было по-прежнему, и (союз)если Володе и(частица) казалось домашнее пространство как будто сузившимся, то это только оттого, что за годы отсутствия он очень повзрослел и(союз) вырос.Запятая нужна после союза "оттого", потому что по правилу составной союз разделяется, если перед ним есть частица (только). Схема:
[- =], и (если - =),[то -  ],(что - = и = ).

Предложение повествовательное, невосклицательное, сложное с сочинением и подчинением, состоит из 4 простых:1)двусоставное полное, распростр.,неосл.;Основа-всё было по-прежнему.

2)придаточное сопоставительное - двусост. полное, распростр., неосл.;основа-пространство казалось сузившимся.

3)главн.-двусост. неполн. с пропуском сказ.(эллиптическое), распр., неосл.;основа- подл. это, сказ. пропущено.

4) придат. причины - двусост. полное, распр., осл. однородными сказуемыми; основа-он повзрослел и вырос.